# Multiple tables load (Php + MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched and found similar questions and answers, though I can't get it work.

**I have two tables:**

**playlist**
(id, name and song_id)

**songs** (id, name)

My address to the php-file is like: `http://example.com/?playlist=30`
I want to fetch the `$_GET['playlist']` and select all the songs from that specific playlist.

like:
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE id=$_GET['playlist']");`
AND from that result I want to select the songs,

like: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE playlist.song_id = songs.song_id");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the tables together in a single query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   playlist JOIN songs ON songs.id = playlist.song_id
WHERE  playlist.id = ?
```

Please don't use `$_GET` variables directly in SQL - it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Also, please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: THANKS! I did know about the $_GET-thing, though I wanted to shorten my story :)
It worked very well, I tried just to copy it and it worked very well!

What do you mean with "ancient MySQL extension" ? I'm a beginner in php so I can't understand?

Comment: @user1427930: The `mysql_*` functions (like `mysql_query` to which you refer in your question) are outdated and the process to eventually remove them from PHP has begun.  You shouldn't be using them anymore (despite the fact that almost all the tutorial sites still teach you to do so).  There are two very good alternatives in PHP, an improved extension (whose use is pretty similar, so it should be easy to switch) and a powerful abstraction layer (which isn't that much harder to use, but enables you to switch database backends in the future to another RDBMS with relatively little effort).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_id IN(SELECT song_id FROM playlist WHERE id=$_GET['playlist'])`;

if your playlist table have song_id columnt

Answer (score 0):

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT s.id,s.name,p.id,p.name FROM songs s inner join playlist p on s.id=p.song_id where p.id=$_GET['playlist']");
```